# edit a html file with a php file

Tags: php, html

I am making a website that automaticly generates a html with some text that you can fill in a form.

but I want that text back in the form once I press a button or something, so you can edit it.

I tried it with fread and fwrite, Javascript and some more.

I use `$_POST` and I cut out the form of the php file.

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        mkdir($_POST['naam'], 0777);
            if (!mkdir($_POST['naam'], 0777)) 
            {

                $uploaddir = $_POST['naam']."/";
                $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['logo']
['name']);

                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'], 
 $uploadfile)) {

                echo $uploadfile;


                echo " succesfull";
                $file = fopen($_POST['naam']."/index.html", "w");
                $code = $code = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>".$_POST['naam']."</title>
</head>
<body>

<main>
    <img src='".$_FILES['logo']['name']."'/>
    <h1 name='naam'>".$_POST['naam']."</h1>
    <div class='contact'>

        <h3>Telefoon: <span id='Telefoon'>".$_POST['Telefoon']."<span></h3>

        <h3>Email: <span id='Email'>".$_POST['Email']."</span></h3>

        <h3>Straat: <span ide='straat'>".$_POST['straat']."</span></h3>

        <h3>plaats: <span id='plaats'>".$_POST['plaats']."</span></h3>

    </div>
    <p class='info'><span id='overig'>".$_POST['overig']."</span></p>
<p class='melding'>Wij zijn bezig aan onze website, coming soon</p>
</main>


</body>
</html>";


            fwrite($file, $code);
                fclose($file);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "failed";
            }
    } 
  ?>
```

Comment: keep your code value is a session variable and if session is available. show it in your site.

Comment: Added code block

Comment: Post the form contents to a URL. Do file_put_content on the form contents. You can also use an onclick settimeout to call the URL with the contents if you want the content written back to the original page and don't want to use a javascript getelementbyid

Answer (score 0):

You have your variable - $code - so simply create a new form with something like this

```
<textarea name="full>".$code."</textarea>
```

Comment: But how will I be able to get parts of the code to that var, cause its placed in the html file as text

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing echo statements to output the server values:

```
 <h3>Telefoon: <span id='Telefoon'>". echo($_POST['Telefoon']) ."<span></h3>
```